# QtableView and model in an infinite while loop

Tags: c++, qt, view, model

I have a QTableview I have a model attached to it. I have a infinite while loop in which I send and receive messages from a server. When I receive a message, I want to add a row to my table.
My problem is that I can't get this idea work. When I do `while (true)` it doesn't work.
i would be appriciate it if someone could help me.
Here is the piece of code that I am talking about:

```
model = new QStandardItemModel(4,1,this);
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView::Stretch);

while (true)
{
    // Server response
    reciever_input.wait_for_recieve();

    std::vector<std::string> res = decode_msg(_serverResponse.front());

    unsigned int it;
    it = 8;

    if (res[0] == "Y")
    {
        int row = 0;
        //here I want to add rows in my table
        for (; it < res.size(); it++, row++)
        {
            std::string temp = res[it]; // this is the string that I want to add
            QString qtemp = QString::fromUtf8(temp.c_str());
            QModelIndex index = model->index(row,0,QModelIndex());
            model->setData(index,qtemp);
        }
    }
    if (res[0] == "L")
        break;
}
```

Comment: When I do while (true) it doesn't work? What doesn't work? Error? Doesn't go into while loop? describe your issue.

Comment: @MarKS I seems that it enters the while loop but doesnot update the table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to make a neu Thread for the server connection? I think you should run it as a second thread in the background and in case of neu datas update your model.

[you can find qt doc here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/thread-basics.html)

you can also find also good examples in youtube

---

additional idea:

MarKS has right, something is missing in your code. Use this code to insert row at the end of model:

```
int rowNr;
rowNr = model->rowCount();  
model->insertRow(rowNr);  //insert new row
model->setData(model->index(rowNr, 1), qtemp );  //in Column 1 - your string qtemp
model->submitAll();  //to hand over
```

Comment: but if I create a seperate thread for server response, how could I update my table if there was a new message from server? by signals? (Sorry I am new to qt)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `insertRow()` inside your `for` loop. Please read through the documentation [here](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qstandarditemmodel.html#insertRow-2).

I haven't tested the code myself, but it should look something similar to the code below:

```
while (true)
{
    // Server response
    reciever_input.wait_for_recieve();

    std::vector<std::string> res = decode_msg(_serverResponse.front());

    unsigned int it;
    it = 8;

    if (res[0] == "Y")
    {
        int row = 0;
        //here I want to add rows in my table
        for (; it < res.size(); it++, row++)
        {
            std::string temp = res[it]; // this is the string that I want to add
            QString qtemp = QString::fromUtf8(temp.c_str());

            // insert row into the model 
            model->insertRow(row, new QStandardItem(qtemp));
        }
    }
    if (res[0] == "L")
        break;
    }
```

**EDIT 1:**

Setting `int row = 0` will overwrite the rows every time you receive a new `std::vector<std::string>`. It is upto you how you want to use this piece of code.

Comment: of course. But the issus is always the same. I have to use multithreading to update my table.